# How to implement thread in succession

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I would like to implement a transfer with socket for transfering pictures and check on the server if the picture is ever loaded and if it is true not transfering the picture simply change the imageView.

I have a client and a server which work for simply transfer picture between 2 devices. But i want to send a hash of each pictures once at each time before send them. My dificulty is primarily on the thread manager, i have implement a listener for the 1st thread (send / receive picture's hash on client / server) to know when it's finished and then start the second thread (send / receive pictures on client / server). But i don't know if my methodology is ok because it doesn't work well (the server receive the hash on the start but not the other).

I hope that i am clear, here is my parts of code concerned, thanks to someone who can give me a solution.

**Server**

private class ReceiverHash extends Thread {

```
    private List<TaskListener> listeners = new ArrayList<TaskListener>();

    public void addListener(TaskListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    void getTaskState(Boolean state) {
        for (TaskListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.getTaskState(state);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(socketServerPORT);

            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            while (true) {
                String str = br.readLine();          // lecture du message
                if (str.equals("END")) {
                    serverSocket.close();
                    getTaskState(true);
                    break;
                }
                hashList.add(str);
                Log.d("HASH_RECEIVER_LOG", str);   // Log debug hash
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private class Receiver extends Thread {

    int pos = 0;
    int cmpt = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // create ServerSocket using specified port
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(socketServerPORT);
            while (true) {

                //checkFileExist();
                File f = new File(getFilesDir(), "img" + Integer.toString(pos) + ".png");
                fileList.add(f);
                Log.d("HASH_RECEIVER_LOG", "Attente d'une réponse du client");
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                Log.d("HASH_RECEIVER_LOG", "Reception d'une réponse");
                f.createNewFile();

                InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);

                byte[] bytes = new byte[2 * 1024];
                int count;

                while ((count = inputStream.read(bytes)) > 0) {
                        Log.d("RECEIVER_CMPT", Integer.toString(cmpt));
                        outputStream.write(bytes, 0, count);
                        cmpt = cmpt + count;
                }
                myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        imgDiapo.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How i use listener on the activity :

```
ReceiverHash receiverHash = new ReceiverHash();
    receiverHash.start();
    receiverHash.addListener(this);
```

**Client**

```
public class Sender extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
private String dstAddress;
private int dstPort;
private String fPath;

public Sender(String address, int port, String path) {
    dstAddress = address;
    dstPort = port;
    fPath = path;

}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

    Socket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

        FileInputStream inputStreamSend = new FileInputStream(fPath);
        OutputStream outputStreamSend = socket.getOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2 * 1024];
        int count;
        while ((count = inputStreamSend.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outputStreamSend.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        outputStreamSend.close();
        inputStreamSend.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (socket != null) {
                socket.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public class HashSender extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>  {
private String dstAddress;
private int dstPort;
String hash;
//private ArrayList <String> listHash;
private List<TaskListener> listeners = new ArrayList<TaskListener>();

public HashSender(String address, int port, String path) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    dstAddress = address;
    dstPort = port;
    hash = sha1(new File(path)); //methode encryption in sha1
}


public void addListener(TaskListener listener) {
    listeners.add(listener);
}
void getTaskState(Boolean state) {
    for (TaskListener listener : listeners) {
        listener.getTaskState(state);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
    getTaskState(true);
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

    Socket socket = null;

    try {
        socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

        OutputStream outputStreamSend = socket.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStreamSend));
        buf.write(hash);
        buf.newLine();
        buf.flush();
        Log.d("toto", hash);
        buf.write("END");
        buf.newLine();
        buf.flush();
        outputStreamSend.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (socket != null) {
                socket.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

How i use listener on the activity :

```
HashSender hashSender = new HashSender(dstAddress.get(i), dstPort, selectedItemPath.get(pos));
                    hashSender.addListener(ControlsActivity.this);
                    hashSender.execute();
```

Comment: Could you show your `ControlsActivity::getTaskState` method? Also I was expecting that your server should return something like `true` for hashes that are already present (the image file) on server, not just storing them inside a `hashList`.

Comment: Actualy i resolved my problem by removing one thread and do all the writer / reader on socket on the same thread. Thanks.